# Multiple wsus client move to specific group in wsus console using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Here it is my code

Im trying to move the content from servername.txt to specific group in wsus console
can anyone tell me what is the error
any answer would be very much appreciated thanks

$content =  Get-Content .\servername.txt

$content | foreach {

$client =$wsus.SearchComputerTargets()

$group = $wsus.GetComputerTargetGroups() | where {$_.Name -eq "Production Servers"}

$group.AddComputerTarget($client)
}

here's my error

Cannot find an overload for "SearchComputerTargets" and the argument count: "0".
At line:4 char:25

- ```
                      $client =$wsus.SearchComputerTargets()
  ```
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Cannot find an overload for "AddComputerTarget" and the argument count: "1".
At line:6 char:25

- ```
                      $group.AddComputerTarget($client)
  ```
- ```
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: You should be using `$_.` instead of `$wsus` with the Foreach-Object you are using. If you want to use a named variable use a foreach loop `foreach($wsus in $content){do something with $wsus}`

Comment: Tried to change from $wsus to $_. still doesn't work